# I cannot receive the call back in cellForItemAtIndexPath (Objective C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, callback, uicollectionview

I am trying to make an app with CollectionView, but I'm facing a problem. As you can see from my code, I received the callback in both numberofSectionsINCollectionView and numberOfItemsInsection, but cannot receive the callback in cellForItemAtIndexPath, which makes the cell not show up inside CollectionView. However, with another computer with the same Xcode version and connected to the same iPhone (6 Plus), I can receive the callback in cellForItemAtIndexPath.

I don't know why. Could you please tell me how to fix the problem? I think it's attributed to the setting in Xcode, but I'm not sure.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
if (self.useSection) {
    return self.dataSource.count;
}
return 1;}


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
if (self.useSection)
    return [[self.dataSource objectAtIndex:section] count];
return self.dataSource.count; }


 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:[self reuseIdentifierForIndexPath:indexPath] forIndexPath:indexPath];
return cell;
 }
```

I double-checked if delegate is set like

```
 self.collectionView.delegate = self;
 self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
```

Comment: 1. Make sure you're returning a non-zero number of sections and a non-zero number of items in that section.
2. Make sure your collection view is laid out properly. If its size is 0, 0, the collection view won't actually try to load a cell.

Comment: u checked the result of     **return [[self.dataSource objectAtIndex:section] count];**.

Answer (score 0):

cellForItemAtIndexPath won't be called if your cell size is (0,0) or count is 0 maybe you can try add this code :

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:
(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ return CGSizeMake(100,100);}
```